# Two metrics in a single chart applicationinsights

Tags: performance, azure-application-insights, dashboard, azure-monitoring, azure-dashboard

I am trying to get multiple metrics in Single chart like comparing Volume or trends for multiple days

Can someone help me with a sample Query in ApplicationInsights how to compare multiple trends ?

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as an answer as per [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top).

Answer (score 1):

From the Metrics Explorer blade in Application Insights, you can create charts that plot **multiple metrics lines** or show **multiple metric charts** at once.

For example, the following screenshot shows 2 charts: one with the Availability Test duration, and the other plotting multiple metrics like Availability test results, Failed requests, and TrackExceptionCalls on a single chart:

[image: Application Insights Metrics Explorer]

Once you have your charts plotted, you can go ahead and pin them to a Dashboard.

Reference: [Create views with multiple metrics and charts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-charts#create-views-with-multiple-metrics-and-charts)

Comment: Thank you,  I am looking for adding a metrics from  log analytics , Is there a sample query that i can take as a reference to create from log analytics custom metrics ?

Comment: @TryingToCode Have you had a chance to check this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/charts? You can play with the Log Analytics Demo environment to work through some sample queries here: https://portal.loganalytics.io/demo